# Windows with No Theme

Tags: windows-10, themes

while trying to install Windows 10 in a VM, I accidentally reset the VM and got an error message with this interesting window bar:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHO7K.png)

I like the way the window of the error message looks, so that got me wondering whether I could replicate that on a normal windows installation.

Is this possible? If so, how do you do it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Set networking in the Virtualizing Application to Bridged for the Guest machine, Use the virtualizing app to reset (Ctrl-Alt-Del) the Guest operating system. Now see if it completes updating. It should.

Comment: My question wasn't about the error.

Comment: The error indicates an Update error. I have not seen Theme create such a message - just updates. There may not be any Theme because install / updates did not finish and in a VM that can occur because it could not see a network.

Comment: I don't care about the error, because I have resolved it. My question is how to achieve the appearance of the error message.